# Specifying cpu-only for pytorch in conda YAML file

Tags: yaml, pytorch, conda, miniconda

I can set up a conda environment successfully as follows:

```bash
conda create --name temp python=3.8.5
conda install pytorch==1.6.0 torchvision==0.7.0 cpuonly -c pytorch
```

I then save the environment to a YAML config file. The looks like this:

```yaml
name: temp
channels:
  - pytorch
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - ca-certificates=2020.10.14=0
  - certifi=2020.6.20=pyhd3eb1b0_3
  - cpuonly=1.0=0
  - freetype=2.10.4=h5ab3b9f_0
  - intel-openmp=2020.2=254
  - jpeg=9b=h024ee3a_2
  - lcms2=2.11=h396b838_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.33.1=h53a641e_7
  - libedit=3.1.20191231=h14c3975_1
  - libffi=3.3=he6710b0_2
  - libgcc-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libpng=1.6.37=hbc83047_0
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libtiff=4.1.0=h2733197_1
  - lz4-c=1.9.2=heb0550a_3
  - mkl=2020.2=256
  - mkl-service=2.3.0=py38he904b0f_0
  - mkl_fft=1.2.0=py38h23d657b_0
  - mkl_random=1.1.1=py38h0573a6f_0
  - ncurses=6.2=he6710b0_1
  - ninja=1.10.1=py38hfd86e86_0
  - numpy=1.19.2=py38h54aff64_0
  - numpy-base=1.19.2=py38hfa32c7d_0
  - olefile=0.46=py_0
  - openssl=1.1.1h=h7b6447c_0
  - pillow=8.0.1=py38he98fc37_0
  - pip=20.2.4=py38h06a4308_0
  - python=3.8.5=h7579374_1
  - pytorch=1.6.0=py3.8_cpu_0
  - readline=8.0=h7b6447c_0
  - setuptools=50.3.0=py38h06a4308_1
  - six=1.15.0=py_0
  - sqlite=3.33.0=h62c20be_0
  - tk=8.6.10=hbc83047_0
  - torchvision=0.7.0=py38_cpu
  - wheel=0.35.1=py_0
  - xz=5.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
  - zstd=1.4.5=h9ceee32_0
prefix: /data/anaconda/envs/temp
```

But if I try making a conda environment from the following file:

```yaml
name: temp
channels:
  - defaults
  - pytorch
dependencies:
  - python==3.8.5
  - pytorch==1.6.0=py3.8_cpu_0
```

it fails, with the following incompatibilities:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Package ld_impl_linux-64 conflicts for:
python==3.8.5 -> ld_impl_linux-64
Package sqlite conflicts for:
python==3.8.5 -> sqlite[version='>=3.32.3,<4.0a0|>=3.33.0,<4.0a0']
Package * conflicts for:
pytorch==1.6.0=py3.8_cpu_0 -> *[track_features=cpuonly]
Package ncurses conflicts for:
python==3.8.5 -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
Package mkl conflicts for:
pytorch==1.6.0=py3.8_cpu_0 -> mkl[version='>=2018']
Package blas conflicts for:
pytorch==1.6.0=py3.8_cpu_0 -> blas=[build=mkl]
Package zlib conflicts for:
python==3.8.5 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
Package openssl conflicts for:
python==3.8.5 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a']
Package python conflicts for:
pytorch==1.6.0=py3.8_cpu_0 -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']
Package xz conflicts for:
python==3.8.5 -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
Package libffi conflicts for:
python==3.8.5 -> libffi[version='>=3.3,<3.4.0a0']
Package libgcc-ng conflicts for:
python==3.8.5 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
Package tk conflicts for:
python==3.8.5 -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
Package pip conflicts for:
python==3.8.5 -> pip
Package ninja conflicts for:
pytorch==1.6.0=py3.8_cpu_0 -> ninja
Package readline conflicts for:
python==3.8.5 -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
Package numpy conflicts for:
pytorch==1.6.0=py3.8_cpu_0 -> numpy[version='>=1.11']
```

Why? How could such a simple configuration, which was cut down from a successful environment, fail? How should I specify the CPU-only version of pytorch 1.6.0 in a YAML config file for a conda environment?

Comment: Try dropping the build-string from `pytorch` and add the metapackage `cpuonly` as a dependency.

Comment: @merv that worked, thank you. Do you want to write that up as an answer? One secondary question, where might I have worked that out for myself, is there documentation for that package, or even mentioning that it is a package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For systems that have optional CUDA support (Linux and Windows) PyTorch provides a mutex metapackage `cpuonly` that when installed constrains the `pytorch` package solve to only non-CUDA builds. Going through [the PyTorch installation widget](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#start-locally) will suggest including the `cpuonly` package when selecting "NONE" of the CUDA option

[image]

I don't know the internals of how to build packages that use such mutex metapackages, but [mutex metapackages are documented](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/packages.html#metapackages) with metapackages in general, and the docs include links to MKL vs OpenBLAS examples.

Exactly why the simple YAML you started with fails is still unclear to me, but my guess is that `cpuonly` constrains more than just the `pytorch` build and having the specific `pytorch` build alone is not sufficient to constrain its dependencies.

Comment: From what I see on installs that do not rely on Conda, but rather on `pyenv` virtual environments, the `cpuonly` metapackage constrains both `torch` AND `torchvision` on CPU only environments. That seems to align with your "guess" !

Answer (score 7):

**Option 1**

Add `cpuonly` as a package

```
name: temp
channels:
  - defaults
  - pytorch
dependencies:
  - python==3.8.5
  - cpuonly
  - pytorch==1.6.0
```

**Option 2**

Add `+cpuonly` suffix to the relevant packages

```
name: temp
channels:
  - defaults
  - pytorch
dependencies:
  - python==3.8.5
  - pytorch==1.6.0+cpuonly
```

Comment: `pytorch==1.12.0+cpuonly` is not working in my case. but the first approach is working fine for me.